# creating a procedure with 2 parameters and throwing an exception

Tags: plsql

How do i create a procedure with 2 parameters func and sal that verifys that the employee's salary is between min_salary and max_salary(2 colums from JOBS table) and if they aren't in it,it need to throw an exception?
Also i'm using the rows from the employees table(salary,employee_id,job_id)So far i got this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_sal(func employees.job_id%type,sal employees.salary%type)
IS
max_sal jobs.max_salary%type;
min_sal jobs.min_salary%type;
empid employees.employee_id%type;
BEGIN
SELECT e.employee_id,e.salary,e.job_id,j.max_salary,j.min_salary INTO empid,sal,func,max_sal,min_sal
FROM employees e JOIN jobs j ON e.job_id = j.job_id
ORDER by e.employee_id;
FOR i IN empid.FIRST..empid.LAST LOOP
IF(sal < min_sal) OR (sal > max_sal) THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'OUT OF BOUND');
ELSE DMBS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OK');
END IF;
END LOOP;
END;
```

I get the error Error at line 10: PL/SQL: Statement ignored.WHAT am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you need to use the rows from the employees table?  Unless I've misunderstood, all you really need to do is to query the jobs table.

Comment: because you need to campare the rows from salary who is a Employees table rows ,we need to compare it for evey employee with min_salary and max_salary who are rows in the Jobs table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just found out that it wasn't necesary to use FOR and the empid variable so the answer is much simpler:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_sal(func employees.job_id%TYPE,sal employees.salary%TYPE)
    AS
    max_sal jobs.max_salary%TYPE;
    min_sal jobs.min_salary%TYPE;
    BEGIN
    SELECT max_salary,min_salary into max_sal,min_sal 
    FROM JOBS 
    WHERE job_id=func;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(max_sal||' and '||min_sal);
    IF sal < min_sal OR sal > max_sal THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20205,'Out of Bounds');
    END IF;
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems you want row by row processing but extract only 1 record. I presume you will get too many rows exception.
2. Empid is ordinal variable but not collection. You should create a table of records and iterate through it so your script fails on FOR i IN empid.FIRST..empid.LAST LOOP.

Comment: well i need to compare every employees salary with the min_salary and max_salary and the are connected by job_id(employees has foreign key job_id and jobs has primary key job_id) that why i tried using the FOR.Also u have a point i mean when comparing i need only 1 record for the current employee then i move to the next.In empid i tried to put all the employee_id rows but yeah you're right i can't put all of them in a simple variable.Thanks for pointing that up!

Answer (score 0):

> Hey i just looked into the question and illustrated a below snippet
>   which will definitely work. I dont have workspace with me but this
>   should work. Let me know for any issues.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_sal(
    func employees.job_id%type,
    sal employees.salary%type)
IS
TYPE max_sal_tab
IS
  TABLE OF jobs.max_salary%type;
  max_sal max_sal_tab;
TYPE empid_tab
IS
  TABLE OF employees.employee_id%type;
  empid empid_tab;
TYPE sal_tab
IS
  TABLE OF employees.salary%type;
  sal sal_tab;
TYPE jobid_tab
IS
  TABLE OF employees.job_id%type;
  func jobid_tab;
TYPE min_sal_tab
IS
  TABLE OF employees.min_salary%type;
  min_sal min_sal_tab;
BEGIN
  SELECT e.employee_id,
    e.salary,
    e.job_id,
    j.max_salary,
    j.min_salary BULK COLLECT
  INTO empid,
    sal,
    func,
    max_sal,
    min_sal
  FROM employees e
  JOIN jobs j
  ON e.job_id = j.job_id
  ORDER BY e.employee_id;
  FOR i IN empid.FIRST..empid.LAST
  LOOP
    IF(sal < min_sal(i)) OR (sal > max_sal(i)) THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'OUT OF BOUND',TRUE);
    ELSE
      DMBS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OK');
      --Do not use dbms output in any prod env
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```